# Who was the first to prove the mean value theorem?

Tags: real-analysis

Who was the first to prove the mean value theorem, i.e., the existence of an intermediate point where the slope equals the average slope over the interval?

Comment: Related: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/184358/what-did-rolle-prove-when-he-proved-rolles-theorem . So certainly Rolle didn't do it, and any proof would have had to be after 1691 (since proving the mean value theorem would have automatically proved Rolle's as a special case). There may be no well-defined answer to the question, because the answer may depend on what people think of as a rigorous proof, and historical judgments about when the real number system was formulated with mathematical precision.

Comment: This article : http://abesenyei.web.elte.hu/publications/meanvalue.pdf : gives a long (and rather repetitive) history, but requires a good grasp of a number of different languages.

Comment: The relevant part of the pdf link posted by Nick R seems to be section 9.

Comment: @NickR, would you care to elaborate a bit and format your *comment* as an *answer*?

Comment: @MikhailKatz I have posted an answer as per your request.  Please note the additional reference which was necessary to clear up an potential ambiguity in Besenyei's paper concerning authorship of the relevant proof.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As per your comment requesting details of the linked paper :

[Besenyei's paper](http://abesenyei.web.elte.hu/publications/meanvalue.pdf) begins with a history of the development of Rolle's Theorem into its general form.  It follows this with the history of various generalisations of Rolle's Theorem equivalent to MVT and attributed to the likes of Cauchy, Bonnet, Serret, Dini, and Harnack.

Looking at Besenyei's paper, at first it would appear that Joseph Alfred Serret is the first to state and prove the result in its modern form, however this is not the case - please see below.  From Serret's *Cours de calcu infinitesimal* of 1868 as Theorem I (translation) :

> Let $f(x)$ be a function of $x$ which remains continuous for values of $x$ between two given limits, and which, for these values, has a well-determined derivative $f'(x)$. If $x_0$ and $X$ denote two values of $x$ between these same limits, the following $$\frac{f(X) - f(x_0)}{X-x_0} = f'(x_1)$$ will hold, with $x_1$ being a value between $x_0$ and $X$.

Besenyei's paper does not include the relevant proof.

This appears on the page denoted 11/15 (lower right hand corner) - page 83/152 of the PDF document.

However, according to [this paper by Renaud Chorlay](http://cerme8.metu.edu.tr/wgpapers/WG1/WG1_Chorlay.pdf), Serret is here simply stating Bonnet's proof. (See page 7 of 16 of the PDF document.)  Thus, the correct answer as to who first proved MVT in its modern form appears to be **Pierre-Ossian Bonnet**. The Renaud Chorlay paper does appear to give Bonnet's proof.

This conclusion appears to be contrary to the [wikipedia entry for the MVT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem) which credits Cauchy as the first to state it in its modern form.  However, Cauchy's statement of MVT is actually and extension of MVT to deal with two different continuous functions $f$ and $g$ which states $$\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{g(b)-g(a)} = \frac{f'(c)}{g'(c)}$$ and which predates the Serret/Bonnet version of MVT.

---

**EDIT**

As Mikhail has pointed out in his comment, the correct answer is in fact Cauchy, as is evident in Besenyei's paper.  Cauchy gives both forms of stating the MVT.

Comment: (1) As Besenyei notes, Cauchy gave both forms of the theorem; (2) As Besenyei notes, Serret presented Bonnet's proof.

Comment: @MikhailKatz I surely must be blind!  Upon re-examining Besenyei's paper, sure enough, there it is as plain as day, Cauchy does indeed give both forms.  Also, Besenyei's presentation of Serret's statement indented under Bonnet's entry is almost as clear.  Thanks for accepting my answer, even if I got it wrong!

Comment: (The link to Chorlay’s paper seems broken.)

Comment: Yes, it's very odd.  Here is an alternative link to [Chorlay's paper](http://cerme8.metu.edu.tr/wgpapers/WG1/WG1_Chorlay.pdf) - perhaps an alternative version of the original link??.  I shall edit the broken link as well.

Comment: It would be interesting to see how solid Cauchy's proof is, and what hypotheses he exploits exactly (differentiability, $C^1$, etc.).

Comment: Likely no solider than Lagrange’s: per Grabiner, Dugac “reviews the proofs by Ampère (1806) and Cauchy (1823), showing their dependence on Lagrange's proof.”

Answer (score 5):

The theorem is black on white in **Lagrange**’s *Théorie des fonctions analytiques*, as the initial case of “Taylor’s theorem with [Lagrange](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Explicit_formulas_for_the_remainder) remainder” (1797, [§§51–53](//archive.org/stream/theoriedesfoncti00lagr#page/49)):

> Hence the value of the quantity $P$ relative to $z=1$ [i.e., $\frac{f(x)\ -\ f(0)}x$] can be expressed as $f'u$, $u$ being a quantity between $0$ and $x$. Likewise (...)
>
> 52. Whence there results finally this new theorem, remarkable in its simplicity and its generality, that denoting by $u$ a quantity unknown but comprised between the limits $0$ and $x$, one can successively develop any function of $x$ and of arbitrary other quantities according to the powers of $x$, thus (...)
>   \begin{align}
> f(z+x) &= fz + x\,f'(z+u),\\
> &=fz + x\,f'z + \frac{x^2}2\,f''(z+u),\\
> &=fz + x\,f'z + \frac{x^2}2\,f''z + \frac{x^3}{2.3}\,f'''(z+u),\\
> &\ \ \&\mathrm c.
> \end{align}

Lagrange also spells out the “Rolle” case in his next book (1798, [pp. 166, 175](//archive.org/stream/bub_gb_T5IQirvZebQC#page/n177)):

> Consideration of the *maxima* and *minima* of parabolic lines led Stirling to a method for counting and bounding real roots in degrees 3 and 4, which **Euler** generalized in his Differential calculus [[§298](//www.e-rara.ch/zut/content/pageview/1174624)]. This method boils down, basically, to Rolle’s (... :)
>
> between two consecutive real roots of the equation $\mathrm F\,x=0$, there always falls a real root of the equation $\mathrm F'x=0$.

So I question the accepted attribution to Cauchy (Wikipedia [2007](//en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Mean_value_theorem&diff=127874760&oldid=127720730), [2016](//en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Mean_value_theorem&diff=726867001&oldid=721633751)) — though of course it all hinges on: “first to prove” *under what assumptions*, and how rigorously? For discussion of that: e.g.

- *Dugac, Pierre*, Histoire du théorème des accroissements finis, Arch. Int. Hist. Sci. 30, 86-101 (1980). [ZBL0447.26003](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0447.26003).
- *Grabiner, Judith*, [**Review of “Histoire du théorème des accroissements finis”**](//doi.org/10.1016/0315-0860(81)90043-4) by Pierre Dugac. Paris (Université Pierre et Marie Curie). 1979. 60 pp. Historia Math. 8, 214-219 (1981).
- *Persson, Lars-Erik; Rafeiro, Humberto; Wall, Peter*, [**Historical synopsis of the Taylor remainder**](http://siba-ese.unisalento.it/index.php/notemat/article/view/18358), Note Mat. 37, 1-21 (2017). [MR3733800](//mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=3733800).

**Edit as requested:**

Briefly, Dugac contends (and repeats in a later [paper](//books.google.com/books?id=_K7iBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA14&dq=%22Th%C3%A9or%C3%A8me+des+accroissements+finis%22) and [book](//zbmath.org/?q=an:1060.01002)) that 1º) Lagrange first singled out, stated, and proved — perhaps inconclusively — the mean-value property for analytic functions; 2º) he was to an extent foreshadowed by Cavalieri (1635, [p. 19](//books.google.com/books?id=WCRqHkVzb80C&pg=PA19)); 3º) the first conclusive or “rigorous” proof in print is by **Dini** (1878, [p. 71](//babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?u=1&id=coo.31924060184227&num=71)). To me this is all rather noncontroversial: the [book](//books.google.com/books?id=iIkpAQAAMAAJ&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=%22Lagrange%27s+theorem%22+Rolle) I learned it from called it “Lagrange’s theorem”. [So](//books.google.com/books?id=vrBFAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA82&dq=%22Th%C3%A9or%C3%A8me+de+Lagrange%22) [do](//books.google.com/books?id=V2hbAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA72&dq=Th%C3%A9or%C3%A8me+de+Lagrange) [quite](//books.google.com/books?id=1yy_H-1NW8wC&pg=PA217&dq=Frequentemente+designado) [a](//books.google.com/books?id=mMPCAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA72&dq=%22Lagrange's+theorem%22) [few](//books.google.com/books?id=LRrvAAAAMAAJ&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=%22th%C3%A9or%C3%A8me+de+Lagrange%22) [others](//books.google.com/books?id=ncxGAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA240&dq=Lagrange's). Current textbooks ([Thomas](//books.google.com/books?id=lVUZAQAAIAAJ&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=%22first+stated+by+Joseph-Louis+Lagrange%22), [Stewart](//books.google.com/books?id=spiaBAAAQBAJ&ots=CXB_c79NrU&pg=PA216&dq=Lagrange), [Petrovic](//books.google.com/books?id=oUfBAQAAQBAJ&ots=YYBotBH3sq&pg=PA106&dq=Lagrange),...) credit it to Lagrange. So do Bottazzini ([1986](//zbmath.org/?q=an:0597.01011), p. 53), Grabiner (1981, [p. 122](//books.google.com/books?id=XuFcx-laQmIC&ots=3UnmA98zu3&pg=PA122&dq=%22Cauchy+was+not+the+first%22)), Edwards (1979, [p. 313](//books.google.com/books?id=ilrlBwAAQBAJ&ots=GYUfO5TRpo&pg=PA313&dq=Lagrange)), Cajori (1910, [pp. 308-311](//babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?u=1&id=coo.31924001049513&num=308)), the *Encyklopädie* (1899, [II A 2 §§7, 11](//archive.org/stream/p1n1encyklopdied02akaduoft#page/65)), and so on all the way to Lacroix (1810: vol. 1, pp. [liv](//www.e-rara.ch/zut/content/pageview/15801244), [385-386](//www.e-rara.ch/zut/content/pageview/15801632); 1800: vol. 3, pp. [vii](//www.e-rara.ch/zut/content/pageview/2483142), [384](//www.e-rara.ch/zut/content/pageview/2483527)). I am beginning to wonder if Besenyei might be the *only* author who doesn’t attribute the theorem to Lagrange?

That said, it is true that a wide shift of emphasis happened between the way Lagrange thought of his theorem and the way we use (and prove) it now. Besides already containing most of the above story, the French *Encyclopédie* article (1912, [II 3 §§11, 22](http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k2025807/f272)) says this well in footnote 116:

> From Rolle’s theorem<sup>114)</sup> one readily deduces<sup>115)</sup> the *mean value formula* which plays a basic role throughout Calculus<sup>116)</sup> and is also, like Rolle’s theorem, basically a mere translation into precise language of the intuitive fact that *B. Cavalieri* had brought to the geometers’ attention.
>
> ---
>
> <sup>114) On the first rigorous proofs of Rolle’s theorem, see *A. Pringsheim* (1900, [p. 454](//babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?u=1&id=mdp.39015053327824&num=454)); see also ***U. Dini*** (1878, [p. 75](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?u=1&id=coo.31924060184227&num=75)); *A. Harnack* (1881); *M. Pasch* (1882); *P. Mansion* (1887); *J. Tannery* (1886); *A. Demoulin* (1902).</sup>
>
> <sup>115) In his lectures at École polytechnique, *O. Bonnet* fully rigorously demonstrated this formula on the basis of Rolle’s theorem. He also gave a proof of Rolle’s theorem which, at least as exposed in *J. A. Serret* (1868, [pp. 17-19](//babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?u=1&id=chi.092051445&num=17)), is far from immune to objections. (...)</sup>
>
> <sup>116) One should note that this fundamental role stems mainly from the mode of exposition of Calculus generally adopted today. For ***J. L. Lagrange***, who took a different point of view, this formula was merely a consequence of Taylor’s formula (1797, [p. 49](//archive.org/stream/theoriedesfoncti00lagr#page/49)).</sup>

To summarize, my take for now (based on these references and subject to your corrections):

1635:  Cavalieri states MVT hence Rolle. (Proof rejected by Guldin, 1640.)
1690:  Rolle proves Rolle for polynomials.
1755:  Euler states Rolle for differentiable functions. (Sketch of proof accepted at the time.)
1797:  Lagrange proves MVT (hence Rolle) for analytic functions. (Proof accepted at the time.)
1823:  Cauchy proves MVT (hence Rolle) for C<sup>1</sup> functions. (Proof essentially same as Lagrange.)
1868:  Bonnet rearranges proof of MVT to rely on Rolle as a lemma.
1878:  Dini proves Rolle (hence MVT now) for differentiable functions. (Our current proof.)

Comment: +1 for an interesting post.  Note that the theorem as stated in Lagrange is apparently incorrect as stated even for an analytic function, since the point $u$ apriori depends on whether you are in the first line, the second line, or the third line.  If you get a chance could you provide a summary of the Dugac/Grabiner/Persson commentary?

Comment: Bonnet's proof does not work for a differentiable (not $C^1$) function whereas according to Besenyei, Cauchy's does.  So it does not seem controversial to attribute the first correct proof to Cauchy.

Comment: All calculus textbooks use the term "Rolle's theorem" even though everybody knows Rolle did not prove what we call Rolle's theorem today. I think the same remark can be made about Lagrange's theorem.

Comment: [Of course](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stigler%27s_law_of_eponymy). Lagrange stated a theorem and gave **a** proof. As with Pythagoras, Rolle, Cauchy-Schwarz, Stokes, etc., setting and generality later evolved.

Comment: I hear what you are saying but a literal application of Stigler's law of eponymy would have the opposite effect, namely that this result would be named after the person who popularized it more than Lagrange did, namely Cauchy.

Comment: On Cauchy, Besenyei (App. 3/5) is clear as mud. Cf. Gispert’s thesis ([1982](//ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=663727), [pp. 18, 45, 73, 105](http://sites.mathdoc.fr/PMO/feuilleter.php?id=PMO_1982)) or ([1983](//ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=710200), p. 78): *“Lagrange and Cauchy* (...) *assume, because of a double passage to the limit, the continuity of the derivative* (...) *Dini was the first to give an entirely correct proof”*. Also Peano ([1884](http://www.numdam.org/issues/NAM_1884_3_3_), pp. 45-47, 252-256).

Comment: Another good exposition of the “official history” (crediting Cauchy no more than Cavalieri, Rolle, Lagrange or Dini) is in Burn ([2000](//ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1778042), [pp. 240-241](//books.google.com/books?id=1nteiLydVpQC&pg=PA240&lpg=PA273&q=Cavalieri+Rolle+Lagrange+Cauchy+Dini)). Dugac (1980) being probably more detailed, it would be interesting if *you* could obtain a scan and address how he is or isn’t right. (I haven’t.)

Comment: NO, I don't have the 1980 paper by Dugac, and I see at google scholar that there does not seem to be any electronic version.  Perhaps the journal could be found in some library (ours doesn't have it).

Comment: Incidentally, even if Cauchy used $C^1$, this is still no worse than Bonnet's proof, and the first proof for differentiable functions is due to Dini. Cauchy's proof is of course much closer to the modern result than  Lagrange's, whose proof I have not seen but as I mentioned already there is a problem already with the statement of the result, since $u$ must depend on the order of the derivative.

Comment: Lagrange only uses finite Taylor polynomials and in no way uses analyticity (the fact that the function equals its Taylor *series*) in his proof. Therefore if one accepts his proof, there is no reason to claim that he proved it in lesser generality than Cauchy.  The question is, is Lagrange's proof acceptable, or is it circular?